# Load resource file based upon path the user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, embedded-resource

I need assistance reading all the resources from a resource file. I am working with visual studio 2010 c# .net 4.0.

I have a user control eg ~/MyFolder/MyControl.ascx. which has local resource files associated with it

I pass the above value ie. path the control, to another of my classes where I want to load the applicable resource file based on the current language.

Is this possible and if so how might i achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way is it to use embedded resources:

```
Assembly _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Project.UI.Assets.Logo.png");
```

This blog post might give you more insight:
http://www.attilan.com/2006/08/accessing-embedded-resources-using.html